# Search and replace for a specific pattern

Tags: javascript

I have the following requirement:

I have a url as

```
var url = '/test/mybin/processes/{testName}/test?id={testId}';
```

The url can contain any number of `{}` in it. Lets say above it has `{}` at 2 places `{testName}` and `{testId}`. It can have any number of such params.

I need to replace the value of each such params with the real value.
I need to first know the name of attribute inside each `{}` and replace them with actual values before loading the url.

Lets say in above example, I have to first extract the names of each attribute inside {} and replace them with actual values.

In my method:

`testName="Test"` and `testId=1`

so, I want the url value to be

```
'/test/mybin/processes/Test/test?id=1'.
```

Could you please let me the best way to achieve this?

Thanks, Tani

Comment: I tried to use a regex var regExp = /\{[^\}]*\}/; and get the matches. But it gives me only the first match.

Comment: You are missing the `/g` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
var obj = { testName : "mytest", testId:1 };

var url = '/test/mybin/processes/{testName}/test?id={testId}';

var regex = /{(.*?)}/g;

var replaced = url.replace(regex, function(m,p1) {
      return obj[p1];
  });

alert(replaced);
```

The regex `/{(.*?)}/` will match any thing between curly braces (non-greedy) and puts the contents in a group that can be replaced.

Your regex from your comments could easily be fixed with the additon of the `/g` flag:

```
/\{[^\}]*\}/g
```

But you may find it easier to add brackets for grouping to make it easier to extract the actual contents between the braces without the braces themselves:

```
/\{([^\}]*)\}/g
```

Also note that in this context the `{` and `}` in your regex don't need escaping, but it doesn't hurt to include the escapes `\`

Answer (score 0):

a regex combined with [String.protoype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) is a nice way to go:

```
function f(map,url) {
    var pattern = /{(\w+)}/g;
    var replacer = function(a,b){
        return map[b];
    };
    var o = url.replace(pattern,replacer);
    return o;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sean9999/poctcdLp